# Append/merge a writeBatch to another writeBatch

Tags: concurrency, rocksdb

I have a job that currently writes to a writeBatch sequentially.
I want to split it into a few threads, since writing to a writeBatch is not thread-safe; I thought that each thread would have its writeBatch, and at the end, all batches will be merged into one to keep the write atomic.

I didn't find an API for it. Does one exist? Any alternative approach I can take?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think such merge/append WriteBatches API exists by looking into https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/include/rocksdb/write_batch.h, which you might already have looked into.

Is there any reason why you'd like to split it into few threads instead of writing to a write batch sequentially? With the above finding of no such an API, it seems that splitting into threads won't give any benefit at least in speeding things up.

If multi-thread with write batch can't be avoided, you may consider implementing your own external synchronization on write batch.